# Making functions autorun in MeteorJs

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, ddp

I am using the page visibility api in my app. I need the value of `document.hidden` to update reactively.

I have a template that when rendered I check if the page is visible and if it is then I set a document property to `false`. Now if the page isn't visible I do want to set the property to false when it does come into view. How should I do this? I tried the template autorun block but it didn't work.

Comment: can you show some code of what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so apparently I was using `document.hidden` and not a event listener. I fixed it.